# rvm installation failing due to "image not found"

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I am trying to install rvm on my mac, however whenever I run:

```
$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled -- ruby
```

I get the following:

```
$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled -- ruby
dyld: Library not loaded:     /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2759)
Abort trap: 6
```

I am unsure what the issue here is, thank you.

Comment: try `brew upgrade bash`  before running the installation

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!